# Sending raw internet packets using C

Tags: c, sockets, raw-sockets

I want to send a raw packet using raw sockets in C language. I made a header file which i can use in my projects. It's named "Inet.h". The Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <linux/if_ether.h>


int createSocket();
ssize_t sendBuffer(int socket, char buffer[], ssize_t length);

ssize_t sendBuffer(int socket, char buffer[], ssize_t length)
{
    return send(socket, &buffer, length, 0);
}

int createSocket()
{
        int _socket_ = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
        return _socket_;
}
```

The method createSocket() works very well, but sendBuffer() always make problems. I made a test Code:

```
#include "Inet.h"

int main()
{
    int socket = createSocket();
    printf("%i\n", socket);

        char buffer[16] = {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P'};
    ssize_t t = sendBuffer(socket, buffer, 16);
    printf("%zd\n",t);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is following:

3

-1

So the Socket, as i said already, works but i don't know why the sendBuffer function will not work. Please help.

Comment: Check `errno ` perhaps?

Comment: send() is well-documented.  A '-1' return is an error.  It's clearly explained.  Google 'send()' or 'man send'.  It's just there.

Answer (score 1):

Your `sendBuffer()` has a bug in it.  When you are passing the `buffer` parameter to `send()`, you are passing the address of `buffer` itself on the call stack, not the address that it points to (the `buffer[]` variable in `main()`). You need to remove the `&` operator:

```
ssize_t sendBuffer(int socket, char buffer[], ssize_t length)
{
    //return send(socket, &buffer, length, 0);
    return send(socket, buffer, length, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `errno` to see what error the OS is providing when your `send()` call fails. Generally speaking, raw socket access requires elevated privileges (which you can grant by running your program with `sudo`, for example).

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to bind your socket with an interface. Something like this:

```
if ( bind( raw, (struct sockaddr*) &info.ll, sizeof( struct sockaddr_ll ))  == -1 )
  perror("binding to interface");
```

To get interfaces, try something like this:

```
if ( getifaddrs( &ifa ) == -1) {
  perror("Couldn't get interface information");
}
```